# Batch encode mp4 With Handbrake CLi, same framesize

Tags: handbrake

Im have about 2000 files that differs little in frame-size and that I need to re-encode to 640x480. Since Handbrake doesn't work that way, maybe CLI is the way to go? Not sure how to work the commands though. I wold need batch conversion, and if possible, output the file to the sourcefplder. If possible, erasing the old in at the same time would be awesome. How would I go about doing this?